How is the amount of electrolyte per kilowatt in a Molten Carbonate Fuel Cell calculated?
While searching for Molten Carboante Fuel Cells I notice that quite a lot of them are really big, for example, this 250 kilowatt MCFC is the size of a truck.
Asking "why it is that big" can't be really answereable...
... But I would assume that a certain amount of electrolyte is required per amount of ions being transported by it, which in turn would be the amount of energy (kilowatt) being generated by it.
If the amount of electrolyte must be determined by its output wattage, then I'm assuming that there must be a way of predicting the amount based on said output.
So, how it is calculated?

Not really? You need a big thing to have 250 kW, because small one would overheat.

It is rather experimentally measured and extrapolated to big scale. Various cells have  determined parameters of energy and power per a unit of weight or volume.
